# Source site links on the recently imported posts list shouldn't redirect

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, redirection, recently-imported

In the 10K tools [recently imported page](https://superuser.com/tools/?tab=migrated) each entry in the recently imported posts list has a link to the post, and a link to the source post that was migrated:

[image: Screenshot of the Unix recently imported posts list]

However, the link to the source post doesn't include `noredirect=1`. Clicking it causes an auto-redirect to the post on the target site, so the two links ultimately lead to the same place. The migrated from box has the correct link:

[image: Screenshot of a migrated from box]

Can the link on the recently imported posts page include `noredirect=1` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These links no longer redirect.

Correct link is

`/tools?tab=migrated`

now as well.